# Nested For loop in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I am trying to loop through the .c files in a specific directory through the makefile.

i used the following code, but it seems not working:

```
DIR= Sources \
     Sources_2

@for entry in ${DIR} ;                  \
do                                         \
    @for i in $${entry}/*.c ;                \
    do                                     \
        echo "Processing $${i}";             \
        #Building Commands go here
    done                                   \
done
```

I get error: "/bin/sh: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use at sign `@` near the second `for` loop. `@` should be used at the beginning of the whole shell command. The following worked for me:

```
DIR= Sources \
     Sources_2

all:
    @for entry in ${DIR};                   \
    do                                      \
        for i in $${entry}/*.c;             \
        do                                  \
            echo "Processing $${i}";        \
        done                                \
    done
```

Comment: @user3438074 This is some error in your Makefile itself, not in the shell script. I have tested the code above and it totally works.

Comment: OK, thanks Oleg, i'll see what's is wrong in Makefile...thanks alot for you help

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Makefile` as below

```
@for entry in ${DIR} ; do            \
    for i in $$entry/*.c ; do     \
        echo "Processing $$i";     \
        #Building Commands go here
    done                              \
done
```

The reason being wrong syntax usage of `for` loop.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Remove the braces for `entry`

Comment: Show the entire `Makefile` which you are using

Comment: @user3438074 : This might be due to not properly formatting the Makefile. Make sure you have used <TAB> and not <SPACE> for a tab width in the makefile